# How to change the bookmark name when dragging <a>

Tags: html

I have the HTML:
`<p>Drag this <a href="https://example.com">link</a> to save this webpage as a bookmark</p>`

So is there a way to change the bookmark name to the title of document rather than link?

Answer (score 0):

The displayed text is the text you see inside the `<a>` tag, so is the bookmark name, simply change it like this:

```
<p>Drag this <a href="https://example.com">Title</a> to save this webpage as a bookmark</p>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the poster was looking for. I have a feeling he's looking to replace with the title of the page returned by the link.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, I indeed meant the title of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in most of the latest browsers, the bookmark is named as the content which is given inside `<title>` tag. So if I bookmark this page, it will be saved as `How to change the bookmark name when dragging <a> - Stack Overflow`. I don't think we can override this ‍♂️